# Stimulus not received to date

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, covid-19, stimulus

I receive SSI via direct deposit also received 2018 SSA-1099 benefit statement. To date I have not receive stimulus. I filled out pertinent info for "My Payment" on the IRS website it stated I did not quality. What is that about, since I certainly do. Please advise.

Comment: Can anyone claim you as a dependent?

Comment: What was the exact message you saw on the Get My Payment website?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have had to do anything it should be automatically deposited into the account your monthly check goes to.